# Updating EF Model: tables missing

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an entity framework (3.5) data model pointing to a remote SQL Server 2005 DB. I've added a few fields to a table in the DB, and wanted to update the model. It's my understanding that refreshing doesn't work and you have to remove and re-add the table, but when I removed it then went to "Update Model from Database", the table wasn't in the list!

If I add a NEW table to the DB, it appears in the list, but if I try to remove and then re-add one, it's not there! I've done this a lot of times in other projects and I can't see why it isn't working with this one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you open the Model Browser for the model there are two Sections, your Model and the Store. I know an issue we used to have was that an object would be deleted from the model but it's definition would still be in the store. At that point every time we updated EF would update the definition in the store but wouldn't regenerate the portion in the model, therefore it would look like it hadn't been imported at all (basically the quasi-existence it sounds like you're stuck in). Ensure it's deleted from both places through Visual Studio and then re-update, this should force EF to treat it as a new entity and generate the objects for both sections.

A second (and more painful) solution would be to open the XML file for the model and search for the entity names, then remove the matching objects. This is a little trickier and unfortunately it's been too long for me to be able to accurately give you instructions on how not to shoot yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: Thanks. I manually edited the store XML and solved the symptom. The problem still exists though (ie tables are deleted from model but not store).
Hopefully I won't have to regenerate the whole model from scratch, I have a lot of store proc functions :(

Comment: Adding fields to a table ought to work fine if you add the field to DB then update, deleting will leave a field behin then you have to remove in the interface. I do remember we had an issue similar to yours but not what we were doing. We found that we could rename the table in the DB temporarily, update the model (table is removed because it has been 'deleted'), then name the table back and re-add it and that would get around the issue of pieces being left behind.

Comment: Thank you! Your post relieved hours of frustration. This still appears to be a problem in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Still a problem in vs2017 as well.

Comment: Ahh, there it is... In the model browser | database | tables. The table I was trying to add was already listed in the store so it wouldn't show up in the list of tables I was able to add from. After I deleted the table from the store, I ran "Update model from database" again. This time the table was visible in the list and I was able to add it!

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove table from model in designer and than re add table.

Comment: Thanks, but I said in my question that I'd tried that.